# How to create a configurable products using Magento Core API

Tags: soap, magento, soap4r

I have no problem importing simple products using Magento Core API (SOAP). How can I create configurable products using the same API? There is no documentation on this at all. A small example would be very useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yet to be able to work out how to associate configurables and simples together with the API. My workaround is to have a SKU format master-size-colour and then a clumsy mySQL script to hook up any stray products. The script can run on a cron.